# Spring Cloud Data Flow REST API composed task arguments not passed to child tasks

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am using the SCDF REST API to launch a composed task. However, the arguments I provide to the task that I launch via tasks/execution do not get passed down to the tasks that make up the composed task.

My endpoint looks something like this:

```
endpoint = "http://mydevserver.com/tasks/executions?name=mytaskname&arguments=--spring.datasource.foo=bar+--spring.datasource.alpha=beta"
```

The task launches and runs the child tasks, but the arguments, which are needed by the child tasks, are not available. I can see in the execution details of the composed task that the arguments are there.

But they do not show up in the execution details of the child tasks.

Seems like I am missing a command or flag or something. I haven't found a way to do this from REST in the docs.

Comment: Arguments being passed to specific child tasks is not currently supported.  We have an open issue for it.  You can use properties however with the same impact.  The issue to follow is https://github.com/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/composed-task-runner/issues/92

Comment: @MichaelMinella is this resolved? I am passing the arguments and It is available for first task however, It is not being passed to respective child tasks. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, this feature was added in Spring Cloud Data Flow 2.6